# Element insert event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a JavaScript event which is fired when a `<tr>` is inserted in a `<table>`?

Or alternatively, is it possible to create a function which will process elements, as they are added or changed? Similar to how jQuery `live` function can propagate click handlers for existing and future elements inside a certain parent element.

Background: I have a table ([jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net)) which is loaded on startup, and then edited locally (certain classes can be added or removed from it). The problem is, I would like to add a certain class to each row based on its contents.

Comment: couldnt you just hook the "add row" button to an event handler?

Comment: Agreed with @toxicate20 otherwise it's just a very bad code architecture

Comment: @toxicate20: I did something like this in the end. DataTables provides a way to create your custom function for fetching data from the server, so I did all of it in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be looking for something like this:

> [DOMNodeInserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html): Fired when a node has been added as a child of
>   another node. This event is dispatched after the insertion has taken
>   place. The target of this event is the node being inserted.

Using it would go something like this:

```
$("table").addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
    alert("something has been inserted");
    console.log(event.target)
});
```

*(I haven't tested it, but it should be the way to go)*

I'd like to add that if you're trying to do this, you probably have some kind of weirdness in your code. There must be a simpler way, maybe going through a simple `addRow(row)` method that would trigger events ?

Comment: Ok, at the end I just used `DataTables` specific hooks: I set the `fnServerData` when creating the `dataTable` to apply the `DT_rowClass` to each row retrieved from the server according to its contents. For later local changes I just used jQuery on individual `<tr>` elements.